# Probability distribution..

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If $Z$ represents number of times $6$ appeared in two independent throws of a die, what would be the probability of $A =${maximum of two throws was $2$ and $Z = 0$}. $Z = 0$ means $6$ appeared $0$ time.

-My try-

Probability of $6$ appears $ 0$ time = $\frac{25}{36}$

maximum of two throws would be $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ or $(2,2)$.

So there are $3$ ways to get maximum of two throws was $2$.

Therefore $P(A) = \frac3{36} \times \frac{25}{36}$ ???

Comment: The events aren't independent. You multiply the probability that the max was two by the probability that there were no sixes given that the max was two. The latter probability is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that you are reporting the problem correctly. The maximum of the two throws is $2$ **and** there are no $6$ precisely if the maximum of the two throws is $2$. So the probability is $\dfrac{3}{36}$.

**Maybe** you were asked for the probability that the maximum of the throws is $2$ **given** that there was no $6$.  Then by using the ordinary conditional probability procedure, we find that the probability the maximum is $2$ given there is no $6$ is $\dfrac{\frac{3}{36}}{\frac{25}{36}}$, which is $\dfrac{3}{25}$.

Comment: By the way  if p(A) = (max of throw is 2 | X = 0)  then, P(A)  = ( max of throw is 2 and X = 0) / (X=0). Then P(A) =  ((3/36)(25/36)) / (25/36)  ??

Comment: Sure, that simplifies to $\frac{3}{36}$, the answer we got from much simpler considerations.